# MKAnnotation via XCTest UI Testing

Tags: swift3, xcode8, mkannotation, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

How can I access the pins on an MKMapView via XCTest's UI Tests?

I want to count the number, verify specific ones are there (based on accessibility id or title), etc.

There doesn't seem to be a XCUIElementType for MKAnnotation.

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on MKMapView + XCTest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The annotation views aren't under `maps` unfortunately. You will find map points of interest there instead. To query for an annotation view you should use `XCUIApplication().windows.element.otherElements["Custom Identifier"]`.

Add the `accessibilityIdentifier = "Custom Identifier"` to your annotation **view**, not annotation. `MKAnnotation` doesn't implement `accessibilityIdentifier`.

Comment: You can just use `app.otherElements["Custom Identifier"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UIAccessibilityIdentification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityIdentification_Protocol/).

```
class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation, UIAccessibilityIdentification {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let title: String?
    var accessibilityIdentifier: String?

    init(title: String?, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}

let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.2853, -73.3382)
let annotation = Annotation(title: "A Place Title", coordinate: coordinate)
annotation.accessibilityIdentifier = "Some Identifier"
let mapView = MKMapView()
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Under test you can reference the annotation via `otherElements`.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let annotation = app.maps.element.otherElements["Custom Identifier"]
annotation.tap()
```

Comment: I'm using an IBOutlet to a MKMapView. XCTest tells me "No matches found for Map" when I try to access: app.maps.element.otherElements["Pin 1"]

Answer (score 1):

In my map i had only 1 pin and i could access to it with **Map pin** identifier like this:

```
    let annotation = app.otherElements.matching(identifier: "Map pin").firstMatch
    XCTAssertTrue(annotation.exists)

    annotation.tap()
```